# Simple line from two points continuing through points

Tags: gnuplot

I simply want to draw a line in 2-D from two points, but have the line continue beyond the two points. The following code works if I want a line segment ending at the points, but I'd like the line to continue on through to the edges. Here's what I have that ends at the points

```
data:
 x  y
 0  4
 1 -1 

reset
set terminal svg enhanced fname 'Times New Roman' rounded dashed standalone
set size ratio 1.0
set xrange[-2:3]
set yrange[-2:6]
set style line 1 \
    linecolor rgb '#0060ad' \
    linetype 1 linewidth 2 \
    pointtype 7 pointsize 1.0
plot data with lp ls 1
```

I want it to keep going through, past the defining points to the edges.

Comment: I don't know how tricky you want to get.  It would be easy from those two points to compute the equation for the line (`-5x+4`).  You could put that in a function and plot that line.

Comment: Yes, that was my first guess, but I'd like to use data and not formulae. So if I did use the standard formula, I still want to stick the points from the data on that nice, continuous line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to obtain a linear function `f(x) = a+b*x` from two points provided as input data, here are three different ones.

### Read (x1,y1,x2,y2) from datablock

One can set up the coordinates as a datablock and use the elements to explicitly calculate `a` and `b`. Unfortunately, indexing a datablock is a bit cumbersome in gnuplot, therefore the function definition becomes quite lengthy:

```
$DATA << EOD
0.0   4.0
1.0  -1.0 
EOD

a(x1,y1,x2,y2) = (y1*x2 - y2*x1) / (x2 - x1)
b(x1,y1,x2,y2) = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)

f(x) = a(word($DATA[1],1), word($DATA[1],2), word($DATA[2],1), word($DATA[2],2)) + \
       b(word($DATA[1],1), word($DATA[1],2), word($DATA[2],1), word($DATA[2],2)) * x

plot $DATA, f(x)
```

Explanation: `$DATA[1]` gives the complete first row, `word` picks the first or second element using the spaces as delimiters.
If your data points should be read in from a file `mydata.dat`, then change the first code block to:

```
set table $DATA
plot 'mydata.dat' with table
unset table
```

Sidenote: Writing the numbers as `1.0` instead of `1` circumvents the pitfall of integer calculations.

### Read (x1,y1,x2,y2) from arrays

If the x and y values are provided in two separate arrays, indexing becomes easier, and the function definition can be shortened:

```
array xvals[2] = [0.0, 1.0]
array yvals[2] = [4.0, -1.0]

a(x1,y1,x2,y2) = (y1*x2 - y2*x1) / (x2 - x1)
b(x1,y1,x2,y2) = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)

f(x) = a(xvals[1], yvals[1], xvals[2], yvals[2]) + \
       b(xvals[1], yvals[1], xvals[2], yvals[2]) * x

plot xvals u 2:(yvals[$0+1]) w lp ls 1, f(x)
```

Or, again, reading from file:

```
array xvals[2]
array yvals[2]
do for [i=1:2] {
  stats 'mydata.dat' every ::i-1::i-1 using (xvals[i]=$1,yvals[i]=$2) noout
}
```

### Make (trivial) fit

One can perform a (strictly speaking non-linear) fit – of course, gnuplot will complain that the error becomes zero:

```
f(x) = a + b*x
fit f(x) $DATA via a,b
# fit f(x) 'mydata.dat' via a,b
plot $DATA w lp ls 1, f(x)
```

[image]

### Edit: 4th variant using `stats`

The `stats` command by default performs a linear fit on any data set it is fed with and create a bunch of STATS_* variables:

```
stats 'mydata.dat' nooutput
a = STATS_intercept
b = STATS_slope
f(x) = a + b*x
plot 'mydata.dat', f(x)
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Is there any text, tutorial that gives this sort of lore? Most gnuplot "tutorials" are one-offers that just throw up a list of examples for you to hack into what you want.

Comment: @147pm Nice to hear that I could help! As for me, I usually combine snippets or code constructs from different sources (mostly SO...) to build something new, kind of like Lego bricks^^ Sometimes I stumble across a tutorial or blog and discover something new: "Oh, that's possible? Good to know!" And then I copy the code to my own application and modify it as needed. But unfortunately I don't have THE source for learning, it's just gathering experience.